# How to synchronise an asynchronous operation?

Tags: c#, winforms, media-player

I have been looking around in this forum as well as in MSDN but I couldn't really find a proper solution for my problem. Probably my approach is not good.
I have the below simple class which has 1 simple method ("PlayAudioFile"). All I want to do is to wait for the playback to complete before letting the method finish and moving on. Since the .Play() is asynchronous, method finishes before playback is completed which is not good for me because I want to playback several files synchronously (1 after the other). I have tried to use AutoResetEvent w/o luck because when playback is over, I dont get into the "MediaEnded" callback.... 1 solution I dont want to use is to have a while () loop busy waiting for a flag raised inside the MediaEnded signalling that the playback is done. It just doesnt seem right.

Any ideas?

```
public class Audio
{
    AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    public void PlayAudioFile(string file)
    {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.MediaEnded += m_MediaEnded;
        mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(file));
        mediaPlayer.Play();
        are.WaitOne();

    }

    private void m_MediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = (MediaPlayer)sender;
        mediaPlayer.Close();
        mediaPlayer = null;
        are.Set();
    }

}
```

Comment: What kind of App? In most types of App you can't afford to 'wait' for an I/O action.

Comment: Hi Henk, It's a WinForm app which uses this above class. The WinForm app needs to playback audio files synchronously, so it basically needs to wait...

Comment: Can you also handle `MediaFailed` event and see if an error occurs before the playback ends. It might seem to end gracefully, though not.

Comment: @user3193529 If you block until the player is done then you'll be freezing your UI for the duration.  You probably don't want to do that, which is why its asynchronous to begin with.

Comment: A WinForms app can't Wait. Find a solution based on events and manage the state your Form is in.

Comment: Also, what version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @Abhinav - Thanks for your reply. no errors occuring, I can hear the playback but it just doesnt enter the MediaEnded...

Comment: @Servy - I use .NET 4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using .Net framework>= 4.5, you can utilize async/await. Your code can be something like this(sorry I code it blindly)

```
await PlayAudioFile(somefile);
```

---

```
public Task PlayAudioFile(string file)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.MediaEnded += (sender, e) =>
        {
            mediaPlayer.Close();
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        };
    mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(file));
    mediaPlayer.Play();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great though in an other case of mine it didn't. I will post a seperate thread for that as requried.

Comment: Also put the mediaPlayer as a field. In my case the audio file only played a really small portion, turned out it was garbage collected.