# MediaPlayer "mediaEnded" not called if Playback is started from a Task

Tags: c#

Continuing [previous related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173429/how-to-synchronise-an-asynchronous-operation), I would like to restructure my question a bit. I still cannot receive mediaEnded event of a MediaPlayer class in case it is invoked from a Task as described below. More deeply, I have a class library named **Audio** which is a sort of building block (I really prefer not having tasks there, just simple methods doing a functionality)

```
public class Audio
{
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    public delegate void AudioDelegate();
    public event AudioDelegate playbackEnded;

    public void PlayAudioFileInMediaPlayer(string pathToWavFile)
    {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.MediaEnded += m_MediaEnded;
        mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(pathToWavFile));
        mediaPlayer.Play();
    }

    void m_MediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = (MediaPlayer)sender;
        mediaPlayer.Close();
        playbackEnded.Invoke();
    }
}
```

On top of that I have a simple business logic layer **BLL** which calls that audio class method. The BLL method must return a Task (it is derived from an abstract BASE class not mentioned here for simplifying and also becasue some other methods in the Audio class may be CPU intensive.

```
public class BLL
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    public Task PlayAudio(string file)
    {
        Audio a = new Audio();
        a.playbackEnded += a_playbackEnded;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                a.PlayAudioFileInMediaPlayer(file);
            });
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    void a_playbackEnded()
    {
        tcs.TrySetResult(true);
    }
}
```

On top of the BLL, we have the **GUI** calling the BLL.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BLL bll = new BLL();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await bll.PlayAudio(@"c:\files\1.wav");
    }
}
```

Still, the mediaEnded event on the Audio class is not called... How come??